# Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution. They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql, exception, runtimeexception

ok I have a wpf app that interacts with a postgresql database, I'm using Npgsql for that matter, when testing everything works great with no exceptions, but when I made a setup.exe to my app and ran it I tried to sign in but it's giving me this exception

[image]

[image]

here's the block that is causing the exception

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            username = user.Text;
            password = pass.Password;

            // Specify connection
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection( // the exception occurs here
                "Server=127.0.0.1;" + // I also tried to set the server url to my pc's ip address on the local network but still the same problem
                "User Id=username;" +
                "Password=password;" +
                "Database=db;" +
                "Port=3500");
            conn.Open();

            // Define a query
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand($"SELECT resid FROM resaccounts WHERE username = '{username}' and password = '{password}';", conn);

            // Execute a query
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                // Specify connection
                NpgsqlConnection conn2 = new NpgsqlConnection(
                    "Server=127.0.0.1;" +
                    "User Id=adminBakri;" +
                    "Password=snoffi9000bakri6;" +
                    "Database=shobek_lobek_db;" +
                    "Port=3500");
                conn2.Open();

                // Define a query
                NpgsqlCommand cmd2 = new NpgsqlCommand($"SELECT name FROM restaurants WHERE id = {(int)dr[0]};", conn2);

                // Execute a query
                NpgsqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr2.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = Encrypt(username);
                        Properties.Settings.Default.UserPassword = Encrypt(password);
                        Properties.Settings.Default.ResId = (int)dr[0];
                        Properties.Settings.Default.ResName = dr2[0].ToString();
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    }
                    catch (Exception exp)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(exp);
                    }

                    this.Hide();
                    Window mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                    mainWindow.Show();
                    this.Close();
                }

                conn2.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error, Wrong info");
            }

            // Close connection
            conn.Close();

        }
```

I also have the latest versions of all the nuget packages including System.ValueTuple and Npgsql.

I followed the steps in this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/create-setup-and-deployment-of-wpf-application-step-by-step/) to make a setup.exe for my app, I don't know what the problem is

help me please, thanks.

**EDIT:** Extra information: I'm not using MVVM

**EDIT: ADDING STEPS ABOUT HOW I MADE SETUP.EXE**

step 1: I added a setup project to my solution.

step 2: I had the following folders.

[image]

step 3: I added the following things to the first two folders.

[image]

so far I have the following:

**In Application Folder:**

[image]

**In Program Files Folder:**

[image]

step 4: I made a shortcut of the file in Program Files Folder and added it to both folders User's Desktop and User's Programs Menu

[image]

step 5: I set the AlwaysCreate property value to True for all the folders.

[image]

step 6: what I did now is rebuild the solution and rebuild the setup project, then I went to the debug folder of the setup project and installed the app from setup.msi.

**and here's my .csproj file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{F2571E19-BB3A-46FA-B1A1-15ECD9392887}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Food_Ordering_Res</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Restaurants Helper</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>main_logo2_qAL_icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject>Food_Ordering_Res.App</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Compile Include="ConfirmLogOut.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ConfirmLogOut.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="IncomeInfoWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>IncomeInfoWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Login.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Login.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MealEditWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MealEditWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="NotificationService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="OfflineMealAdditionInfoWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>OfflineMealAdditionInfoWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="RelayCommand.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Splash.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Splash.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UserControlAddCategory.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UserControlAddCategory.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UserControlAddMeal.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UserControlAddMeal.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UserControlCheckBalance.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UserControlCheckBalance.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UserControlEditMeal.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UserControlEditMeal.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UserControlExpenses.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UserControlExpenses.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UserControlHome.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UserControlHome.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UserControlOfflineMealAddition.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UserControlOfflineMealAddition.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Page Include="ConfirmLogOut.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="IncomeInfoWindow.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Login.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Page Include="MealEditWindow.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="OfflineMealAdditionInfoWindow.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Splash.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="UserControlAddCategory.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="UserControlAddMeal.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="UserControlCheckBalance.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="UserControlEditMeal.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="UserControlExpenses.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="UserControlHome.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="UserControlOfflineMealAddition.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <Resource Include="main_logo2_qAL_icon.ico" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Resource Include="Assets\home.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\1.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\2.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\3.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\4.png" />
    <Content Include="Fonts\ae_Dimnah.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="LoadingIndicators.WPF">
      <Version>0.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MaterialDesignColors">
      <Version>1.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MaterialDesignThemes">
      <Version>2.3.1.953</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts">
      <Version>10.0.18362.2005</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <Version>12.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql">
      <Version>4.1.3.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Portable.BouncyCastle">
      <Version>1.8.6.7</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp">
      <Version>106.10.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Buffers">
      <Version>4.5.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Memory">
      <Version>4.5.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors">
      <Version>4.5.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe">
      <Version>4.7.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime">
      <Version>4.7.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml">
      <Version>4.7.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web">
      <Version>4.7.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json">
      <Version>4.7.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions">
      <Version>4.5.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple">
      <Version>4.5.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: You need to include specific details about how you added the assemblies because you did it incorrectly and that is causing your problem. Seeing step by step how you did it will help us point out the step you made a mistake on. Also edit your question to include a copy of your `.csproj` file

Comment: @ScottChamberlain okay I'll post them right now

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I added what you asked

Comment: not sure what your problem is, the .csproj looks fine to me. I don't see the normal things that would have caused the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might seem like a long solution to your problem but depending on what Dean said, you should try to make a new project and set the target framework to .Net Framework 4.6.1 and then copy all your files from your old project to the new one, and then try everything all over again.

hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Your csproj file is targeting .NET Framework v 4.8 which has System.ValueTuple already baked-in. I suspect that there is a conflict between the baked-in version and the version you are adding as a Nuget package.

Simply removing the `PackageReference` for `System.ValueTuple` (remove Nuget package) and re-build should do the trick, There might be some 'using' references in your code that you'll need to remove too.

Comment: I tried removing the package and it's still not working, thanks for the answer tho

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with 'System.Numerics.Vectors.dll' and none of the above solutions worked for me.

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: generalException
Message: An error occurred sending the request.
 ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.
```

Warning in Visual Studio:

```
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics.Vectors" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
```

I had tried :

1. Changing assembly version to both 32 and 64
2. Adding assembly binding in App.config :

   ```
   <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
           <dependentAssembly>
               <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors"
                                 publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                                 culture="neutral" />

               <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
           </dependentAssembly>
       </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
   ```
3. Changing .Net framework version from 4.7.2 to 4.6.2, 4.8
4. Deleting App.config file completely
5. Clean, rebuild with delete bin, obj folder etc.

Debugging the application, and even running the exe was working perfectly fine.

Finally I realized that only version 4.0.0.0 of 'System.Numerics.Vectors.dll' was present in GAC and the version 4.1.4.0 was missing (I used ildasm.exe to find the assembly version of dll).

Then the solution was to install the missing version dll using `gacutil -i fullPathOfDll`. And it worked!